# Can you combine parts from multiple miners?

Tags: mining-hardware, antminer, asicminer

Is it possible to assemble multiple boards with required chips to create a home miner?
I have seen some miners with certain amount of boards and chips on them, so I was wondering if I can substitute those 3 boards with 10 boards+ chips for better hashrate to be like an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Bitmain's current Antminer products like the S19 are not designed to be user upgradeable in the way you suggest.

[Bitmain's products](https://www.bitmain.com/products/antminer/) that support plug-in expansion are the AntRack and AntBox, but these are really industrial units and not what most people would describe as home units.